# Confusion about nginx location priority

Tags: nginx

example:

```
location /images/a/ {
    return 200;
}
    
location ~ \/images\/a\/test\.png$ {
    return 502;
}
location ^~ /images/{
    return 501;
}
```

My confusion is when I visit http://website.com/images/a/test.png, the response code is 502 instead of 501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration):

> nginx first searches for the most specific prefix location given by literal strings regardless of the listed order.

So the selected prefix location is `location /images/a/`. As this location is not marked with the `^~` modifier, the *regular expression* locations are then processed in sequence order until a match is found.